# ASP.NET MVC5 dynamic submenu with links generated from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, submenu

I need to have a submenu(Executive Sections) for a section called 'Executives'. This menu must show up when a user clicks Executives in the main menu and remain as long as any submenu link of Executives is clicked.
Catch is: the submenu links are dynamic and come from the DB/CMS system, so it's not a hard-coded list. Which is where my woe begins.
Currently, I have it in a PartialView that requires a model of IEnumerable so it can build dynamically.
But how I go about making this work as I need it too is a little twisted up in my mind.

```
@using xxx.Models
@model IEnumerable<xxx.Models.ExecutiveSection>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
@foreach (ExecutiveSection es in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(es.SectionName, "Section", "Executive", new { id = es.ExecutiveSectionId })</li>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Did this in the _Layout

```
 @{ // Sub-Menu for Executive Sections
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("Executive"))
            {
                Html.RenderAction("ExecutiveSubMenu", "Executive");
            }
        }
```

And in the controller:

```
public ActionResult ExecutiveSubMenu()
    {
        // get sections
        var sections = db.ExecutiveSections.ToList();
        return PartialView("ExecutiveSubMenuView", sections);
    }
```

and finally the Partial:

```
@using xxx.Models
@model IEnumerable<xxx.Models.ExecutiveSection>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach (ExecutiveSection es in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(es.SectionName, "Section", "Executive", new { id = es.SectionName.Replace(" ", "-") }, null)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

(I 'replace' the spaces in any section name with dashes '-' and back again for SEO friendliness.)